# home network - user authentication and internet restriction

Tags: windows, networking, authentication, internet

I have a home network (using a WRT54GL).  I have 1 wired desktop, 4 wireless laptop/desktops and a Tablet (Android).

I want to be able to restrict internet access based on specific users.  Some of the laptops/desktops are used by myself, others by my kids.  Restricting by IP/MAC won't work.

Ultimately, I'd like to do /home drives, file shares, printers, etc.  All the current machines (except the tablet) are Windows 7 or XP (pro).

The proxy approach - [outlined here](https://serverfault.com/questions/81601/require-authentication-to-use-the-internet) - is one option for the internet restriction.

I can setup a small server box if needed (likely using older hardware, trying not to sepnd a lot of money).

What's my options?  Suggestions?

Comment: What controls are you looking for? In other words, you say 'I want to be able to restrict internet access based on user', but what type of restrictions are you looking for? Time? Website names? Content restrictions? Why not http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-can-I-control-with-Parental-Controls ?

Comment: Parental controls won't work, because a) the primary machine the kids use is XP pro, and b) they use both laptops and the desktop. I don't want to have to make multiple sets of changes to multiple machines.

As to the restrictions... it's mostly going to be whitelisted... only certain sites they can visit.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended doing what that link in your post said to do.

You do not need to set up a "Small Server Box" Flash your WRT54GL with a custom firmware (I use [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index)) and you can install a proxy like Squid right on it and set up the router to not allow outbound port 80 traffic unless it passes through the proxy.

Here is a [wiki link](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Transparent_web_proxy) for setting up the port forarding. [Here is a post](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=80678) about installing Squid. Go to the [DD-WRT forums](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/) for more help if you need it while setting it up.